# Why readr::read_csv2() command not found in Rmd?

Tags: r, knitr, readr

I'm trying to create a R notebook file, and I get stuck right in the beginning of my code, when trying to read the .csv file.
I have a first chunk, all good at this point:

```
library(readr)
```

But then I try to load my data with:

```
my_data <- read_csv2(".Data/my_data_2021-06-29.csv")
```

and I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: load: command not found
```

Same error with `read_csv()`, `read.csv()` and `readr::read_csv()`. All works fine in RStudio, but not in the .Rmd file.

I'm working on a Mac, with macOS Catalina 10.15.7, R version 4.0.5, RStudio version 10.4.1106, and I also updated all my packages with `Tools > Check for Package Updates…`

Does anyone know how to solve this?
I saw similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456144/rscript-command-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125986/r-markdown-cant-access-bash-command-installed-through-conda-anaconda), but they were about using functions in other situations (anaconda and command line), and I saw no solution for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895260/how-do-i-stop-knitr-from-trying-to-call-system-on-my-engine).

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show your RMD codes

Comment: how are you trying to run the code? running the chunk or knitting the whole document?

Comment: Where exactly is the `/bin/sh: load: command not found` error appearing? That doesn't seem like an R error message. How are you trying to use this file outside of RStudio?

Comment: Digging into the .Rmd code made me realise my mistake, thanks @akrun

Comment: In response to @MarceloAvila and `@MrFlick, I was running the chunk only, in an .Rmd file in Rstudio. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realised it was my mistake when writing the code.
Here are the details in case someone does the same.

Usually the code chunk starts with a line where, among other parameters, the code language is set:

```
{r, echo = F}
my_data <- read_csv2(".Data/my-data_2021-06-29.csv")
```

And I edited this line, thinking I was giving the chunk a title, but I was erasing the language it is supposed to be read, therefore the error output I was having:

```
{load data, echo = F}
my_data <- read_csv2(".Data/my-data_2021-06-29.csv")
```

So the correct form is the first one.

Comment: glad you found the issue. You can still add a name to your chunk with \`\`\`{r load data, options}```. Just keep the `r` there.

Comment: also, you may close the question by marking that your answer solves your question.